# How to create Sprite with url?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

i’m working on an cross platform app (iOS, Android) with cocos2dx v3.0. I want to create a CCSprite with URL. I think there is no cocos-way to do this, so I have to fork my code for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to Http request the image url and once you got the response, you can create image from that response data and save it to your phone. After that you can create the sprite from the save image.

    void ClassName::downLoadImage()
    {
            std::string strImage = "img.png";

            CCHttpRequest* request = new CCHttpRequest();
            request->setUrl("url of your image");
            request->setRequestType(CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
            request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(ClassName::onImageDownLoaded));
            request->setTag(strImage.c_str());
            CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
            request->release();
    }

    void ClassName::onImageDownLoaded(CCHttpClient* pSender, CCHttpResponse* pResponse)
    {
        CCHttpResponse* response = pResponse;

        if (!response)
        {
            CCLog("No Response");
            return;
        }
        int statusCode = response->getResponseCode();

        char statusString[64] = {};
        sprintf(statusString, "HTTP Status Code: %d, tag = %s", statusCode, response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
        CCLog("response code: %d", statusCode);

        if (!response->isSucceed())
        {
            CCLog("response failed");
            CCLog("error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
            return;
        }
        std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();

        CCImage * img=new CCImage();
        img->initWithImageData(&(buffer->front()), buffer->size());

        // Save image file to device.
        std::string writablePath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
        writablePath.append(response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());


         //Now create Sprite from downloaded image
         CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create(writablePath.c_str());
         addchild(pSprite);
    }
```